# This beautiful Aloe is dying! Please help?

Tags: plant-care, aloe

Have this magnificent Aloe plant that is huge and a friend doesn't know what to do. It's so wilted and there is dry dead leaves everywhere. I'd seems to big for the pot.. bulging out the top. What can I do. It hasn't been getting sunlight

Comment: Do you think you could upload a photo of the plant

Comment: Yes, a photo, but you have not mentioned care.  Does this friend water the plant often or not at all.   Some people think succulents do not need any water.  Others water them, even when they do not need it.  If its bulging at the pot, it may not be getting enough water or maybe there is no hole in the pot and it's getting too much.               They do need light.  Aloes are light lovers, many need bright indirect, diffused or morning light, but other want all day light, but no matter the aloe it will be wanting some light.

Answer (score 1):

I think a photo would be great, because it's hard to properly diagnose an issue without seeing the whole picture. I'll amend my answer if you post a photo that reveals more information about your plant.

However, from your description, it doesn't sound like it's in any of the right conditions. Wilting leaves indicates it's getting too much water (is it soft and mushy at the base?). If it's bulging out of the pot, it 100%  needs to be  repotted. Aloe is a succulent and requires a good amount of sun. So if it's not getting sun, yeah, it's going to die.

Here are some tips to try to bring it back to health:

- First, as long as there are no signs of root  rot, repot the plan in a well draining pot with well draining sand cactus/succulent soil.
- Give it a little water to help settle the soil, but not much. The
  soil should be completely dry between watering. It is better to
  underwater than overwater.
- The aloe plant LOVES sunshine, and needs 6-8 hours of full sun. It can tolerate other conditions, but if you want it to be healthy, put  it in a full sun window (south facing if you're in the norther hemisphere).
- The plant is tolerant of various types of weather, but should be kept inside during the colder months.

[HERE](http://www.aloeplant.info/treat-your-aloe-as-you-would-like-your-aloe-to-treat-you/) is a great article on aloe care with more detail than I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Repotting your precious aloe plant carefully might help. If the roots are too big, there maybe not enough nutrients in the pot.

If there is no sunlight, try moving the plant to a sunny spot. A plant needs photosynthesis to survive well.

Is there any pests around? Is there any bugs roaming around in the soil? If so, use plant friendly pesticides.

Are you giving it a lot of water? You may be giving too much water to your plant and that may rot the roots. try reducing the amount of water you give to your plant.

Are you not giving water to your plant? Try to pour some mineral water every time the soil starts to get dry.

There may be other reasons but due to not seeing a photo, I cannot understand the problem well. Hope your plant gets better!